# Matching string with things from array in a for loop with indexOf, error

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm having a little problem with finding and displaying strings from an array. Haven't done any sort of code in years so I'm kind of rusty. My problem is this:

Say I have an array like this:

```
var titles = ["0","Little Mouse", "1","Shaman Disciple", "2","Accomplished Shaman", "3","Shaman", "4","Little Pixie"];
```

(the numbers before the titles are the title id's which are used, I just use titles[i-1] to fetch it, it's pretty important they're in that sort of order!)

And that I wanted to find every string in that array that contains "little" and display its corresponding number. I came up with this, but it won't work and I've already tried reading a bunch about loops and writing over stuff, but I just can't figure it out.
I came up with this script:

```
var x=document.getElementById("title").value;
var xs=x.toLowerCase();

    for(var i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++){
        if(xs.indexOf(titles[i].toLowerCase()) != -1){
            document.getElementById("command").innerHTML = "/title " + titles[i-1];
        } else {
            document.getElementById("command").innerHTML = "no title like that";
        }
    }
```

It's set to go on onkeyup="dostuff()" on a textfield (which I know can't be healthy or good code, but whatever), and it DOES work if you put in the full string, it just doesn't display all the matches in the array. I do get that I SHOULD use innerHTML += blahblah and not innerHTML = blahblah, BUT it just adds to the titles indefinitely! What the hell do I do
Sorry for the wall of text!

Comment: Do you want the title or the number as your result? Why is your array like that in the first place, really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome back to programming and to StackOverflow. There are a ton of resources available these days, especially if you are using JavaScript.

Most browsers now include a built-in debugger and other helpful development tools.

There are also several online resources where you can write and test code without having to worry about hosting. A popular one is JSFiddle.net.

I found several problems in your code:

1. You loop index is incrementing the `i` variable one too many times.
2. The order of the `xs` and `titles` variables in the call to `indexOf` were the opposite of what they needed to be.
3. You need to ignore blank `xs` because it always matches.
4. You need to accumulate the matching items somehow and output them after exiting the loop.

So after the fixes, the code looks like this:

```
var x=document.getElementById("title").value;
var xs=x.toLowerCase();

var found = [];
if (xs) {
    // was "i <= titles.length"
    for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
        // was "xs.indexOf(titles[i].toLowerCase())"
        if (titles[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(xs) != -1){
            // need to add items to list here
            found.push(titles[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}

// this logic needs to be outside of loop
if (found.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("command").innerHTML = "/title " + found.join();
} else {
    document.getElementById("command").innerHTML = "no title like that";
}
```

And here it is on JSFiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/qa4x7b8t/4/

Again, welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure to upvote and accept the useful answers.

Comment: Ooooh, thank you so much! What a nice and detailed explanation! :)
It's neat with the array of results, I think I tried that but managed to mess it up.
All in all, it seems so simple now that I look at it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the index of `xs` inside `titles[i]` but you're looking for title inside xs.

It should be `titles[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(xs) != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle for your solution [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as541986/yet24Lnj/2/)
For loop should run less than the length of the array not equal to and string should be replaced at the end of the for loop

```
var titles = ["0","Little Mouse", "1","Shaman Disciple", "2","Accomplished Shaman", "3","Shaman", "4","Little Pixie"];
var x="Little";  //test string
var serchStr=''; 
var xs=x.toLowerCase();
for(var i = 0; i <titles.length; i++){

    if(titles[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(xs) >-1){

        serchStr += "/title " + titles[i-1];
    } 
}
if(serchStr=='')
    serchStr = "no title like that";
alert(serchStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function findInRetardedArray(find, retardedArray){
  var r = [], f = new RegExp(find, 'i');
  for(var i=0,l=retardedArray.length; i<l; i+=2){
    if(retardedArray[i].match(f)){
      r.push(retardedArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return r;
}
// run the below on an Event instead of in the console
console.log(findInRetardedArray(document.getElementById('title').value, titles));
```